# How to get a textView value from ListView adapter onClick button inside same view?

Tags: android, listview

I have a list View which contains imageView working as button and a TextView.

[image]

what I want is when I click on the button for example for the third item in the list view I want to get the text that in the textview when I click on the button which is in the same position as the text view..

I'll try with

```
 final TextView txt= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
 String txt2 = txt.getText().toString();
```

That's work more and less.

**my problem it's so strange, I will try to explain with images**

When I click on the button irrespective of the position, allways it return the textview which display on the fisrt position on the screen (not on listview, on screen)

**for example**
[image: uno]

On that situation, (red square its screen) if I clicked on the button from the item 1,2 or 3 it return `tv_1`.

**other example (again red square its screen)**
[image: dos]

Now, if I click on the button from the item 2,3 or 4 it return `tv_2`

that is, always it displays the top of the list of visible item on screen

**My code**

```
 public void btn(View view)
    {

        final TextView tv_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_id);

        String txt = tv_id.getText().toString();

Log.i(LOGTAG, "" + txt);
}
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

The problem its because I need to use `final` variable to get only that textview, then its report first one item is displayed on screen, but... why? or how to solve?

**UPDATE 2 MY XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="26dp"
        android:id="@+id/lay_fondo">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/cardview_notify"
            >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="90dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="@color/primary_green"
                    android:id="@+id/lay_prioridad"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:weightSum="1">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:layout_width="580dp"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_weight="0.54">

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                                    <LinearLayout
                                        android:orientation="vertical"
                                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                        <TextView
                                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                            android:text="id"
                                            android:id="@+id/tv_id"
                                            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                            android:textColor="@color/black"
                                            android:textSize="30sp"
                                            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                            android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"/>


                                    </LinearLayout>
                                </LinearLayout>

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:orientation="horizontal"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                                    android:id="@+id/img_favorito"
                                    android:src="@drawable/star"
                                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                                    android:layout_onClick="btn"/>
                            </LinearLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Start moving to RecyclerView

Comment: Hi @ADK, I have the same problem. How can RecyclerView solve the problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace the below line

```
final TextView tv_id = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
```

with

TextView tv_id = (TextView) ((View) view.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.tv_id);

The above line finds textview with in the given view, 
**OR**

Add an `OnItemClickListener()` for and list view

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final TextView tv_id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_id);
        String txt = tv_id.getText().toString();
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "" + txt);
    }
});
```

Comment: I can´t because I need use onItemClickListener to do another action, I need independent onClick events

Comment: then you can follow the first method, add onClick="btn" in the xml for parent layout of the listitem.

Comment: it's just like I have it, i use `setOnClickListener` and `onClick= btn` on XML file

Comment: No, for this reason I'm asking here haha

Comment: I'll try and I'll write you again

Comment: okay, I write `TextView tv_id = (TextView) ((View) view.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.tv_id);`now how I can get text? I can't do `getText` its reports `NullPointerException`

Comment: add onClick="btn" for the button.

Comment: post you list item xml code so that in can help you better

Comment: add one more get parent like 
final TextView tv_id = (TextView) (((View) view.getParent().getParent()).findViewById(R.id.tv_id));

Comment: Hi guys, any solution? I have exactly the same problem. I can't use the onItemClickListener because I already use it for when a user clicks on the list item. But my extra Button need to do another function. How did you solve it?

Comment: I just solved the problem with `TextView tv_id = (TextView) ((View) view.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.tv_id);` thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set onItemClickListener to your listView

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final TextView txt= (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            String txt2 = txt.getText().toString();
            Log.i(LOGTAG, "" + txt2);
        }
    });
```

OR

Set click listener for TextView inside your

```
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Comment: I can´t because I need use onItemClickListener to do another action, I need independent onClick events –

Answer (score 0):

my suggestions;

tv_id is referencing only one item (R.if.tv_id). for this matter wherever you put your button, it will always call the code handled by tv_id.

I suggest you reference the list view and setonclicklistener on the listView.

```
ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 

         int      position, long id) 

         {

                    String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), item,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



          }
```

Comment: I already use this method in the same list, then i need another onClick event for the button

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to get the text in so complicated way?
I assume you have your custom `ListView` adapter (e.g. `MyAdapter`) and your items (e.g. `MyItem`) with a getter (e.g. `MyItem :: getText()`, don't mind C++ style).

Then your approach could be:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // Probably this check is not that necessary but better safe than sorry
        if (listView.getAdapter() instanceof MyAdapter) {
            MyAdapter adapter = (MyAdapter)listView.getAdapter();
            String text = adapter.getItem(position).getText();
            // Do whatever you need with the text
        }
    }
});
```